# Lottie Web - playing an animation once and then triggering a loop

Tags: loops, animation, lottie

https://codepen.io/japongnet/pen/rNRdNXL

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-interactivity@latest/dist/lottie-interactivity.min.js";></script>

   

<div class="spacer">Spacer</div>

 <lottie-player id="firstLottie"
        src="https://lottie.host/ad6435af-2afe-4b3e-85c1-91dc5489a11f/Ta9odNX568.json"
        style="width: 800px;"
      ></lottie-player> 
 
<div class="spacer">Spacer</div>
```

```
.spacer{
  height:100vh;
  border:1px solid red;
}

#firstLottie{
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```
  LottieInteractivity.create({
    player: '#firstLottie',
    mode: 'scroll',
   actions: [
      {
          visibility: [0, 0.5],
          type: "playOnce",
          frames: [0, 60],
      },
      {
          visibility: [0.5, 1],
          type: "loop",
          frames: [61, 300]
      }
    ]
  });
```

I’ve been trying to get an animation playing correctly with the Lottie web player, but I’ve been running into some difficulty.

I would like the animation to trigger on scroll, playing the first 60 frames. After that, I would like to loop frames 61 to 300. I can currently manage a somewhat janky version of this by using two scroll triggers, but i’d much rather the 61-300 frame loop to simply begin automatically after playing frames 0-60, without any additional scrolling required.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? I’ve tried searching through some of the docs but can’t figure out how to do this.